# MPMoviePlayerController video and audio are out of sync

Tags: objective-c

I am using MPMoviePlayerController to play a movie within an application that uses Cocos2D. However when the movie runs, it only plays the last 2/3 of the audio for the movie. It's not that the movie is silent for the first third. When the movie starts playing, it starts playing the audio where it would be 1/3 of the way into the movie. In other words, the audio and video are out of sync.

I am using iOS 4.2 and I have upgraded to the latest xCode. Below is the code I am using. Can someone tell me why this is happening.

```
- (id) init
{
   self = [super init];
   if (self != nil)
   {
       NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]    
                           pathForResource:@"SomeMovie" ofType:@"m4v"]]; 
       MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]  
                             initWithContentURL:url]; 
       // Register to receive a notification when the movie has finished playing. 
       [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                    selector:@selector(PlayBackDidFinish:)         
                                        name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
                                               object:moviePlayer];  

       moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone; 
       moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES; 
       [moviePlayer.view setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((float)M_PI_2)]; 
       [moviePlayer.view setFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
       [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:moviePlayer.view]; 
   }
   return self;
}

- (void) PlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [notification object]; 
              [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self 
                                     name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
                                              object:moviePlayer]; 

    [moviePlayer.view removeFromSuperview]; 

    [moviePlayer release];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Alright, after suffering the same problem, I dug in a little deeper and came up with a different solution.  My problem was slightly different.  I was using the movie player mid-app, so Nathan's suggestion to use the movie player before Cocos2D did it's bit wasn't effective.

It turns out that MPMoviePlayerController has this enigmatic property called useApplicationAudioSession which is set to YES by default.  Setting this property to NO "causes the movie player to use a system-supplied audio session with a nonmixable playback category." (courtesy [Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006953-CH3-SW106)) and, incidentally, fixes the lag problem.

I rely on CocosDenshion for audio and perhaps the application audio session, as defined and utilized by CocosDenshion, is incompatible with the audio session required by the movie player.  This is a total speculation though, but it may be a theory as to what's going on.

Either way, if you use the system supplied audio session, the video playback is suddenly in sync.

Answer (score 0):

Have you played this movie in another app (like the Quicktime player) to verify that it's not corrupted?

Comment: Yeah I have. I played it in iTunes and it worked as expected.